# Is there a 30A receptacle which will accept "regular" 5-15 and 5-20 plugs?

Tags: electrical

In my California residence say I have a 30A circuit.

I would like to be able to plug in "normal" household devices that typically use a NEMA 5-15 or 5-20 plugs.

I can accomplish this with an adapter but are there any code compliant receptacle configurations I can use which would not require an adapter?

Edit: This is for a location inside the house.
Also I note the cynical comments about wanting to plug 20A devices into a 30A circuit. They are not very relevant since in asking for a code-compliant solution. For example code-compliant 15A receptacles are rated for 20A passthrough even though they are NEMA 5-15. So they will not melt when people plug in power strips and draw over 15A from them. Code explicitly allows 15A receptacles on 20A circuits for this reason. The question I'm asking is whether there are code compliant approaches with 30A circuits as well.

Specifically, this circuit powers two powerful plug-in subwoofer for a theater. I used a 10awg wire to run it. It's currently on a 20A breaker and has a 20A receptacle. Each subwoofer is on opposite sides of the mwbc.

I deliberately oversized it because large amplifiers can have high peak loads. The amplifier uses a NEMA 5-20 plug.
I want to upsize the breaker from 20A to 30A to prevent nuisance trips for peak loads. But I know that i am not allowed to simply put a 20A NEMA 5-20 receptacle on a 30A breaker.

Hence my question: is there a code compliant receptacle solution that doesn't require an adapter?

Comment: So you want use what is made for 15 or 20 amps on a circuit that can deliver 30 amps(also probably 240 volts compared to 120 volts).  After the fire, your insurance claim will be denied also.

Comment: There are some real, proper, permanent solutions. Need more details: What location? (inside house, garage, shed, etc.) Does the current circuit have 2 hots + neutral or just 2 hots? Do you ever need to use the circuit as a 30A (e.g., unplug dryer temporarily to use other stuff and then switch back to using it for a dryer)?

Comment: I am sure if you look on the imports from china you can find a device to do exactly what you want , then the insurance company will do exactly what crip659 mentions. With that said shopping questions are off topic and we don’t support things that would be a fire hazard.

Comment: Is this circuit 120V, 240V, or 120/240V?  What are you trying to plug into it, and are there other receptacles/devices on it?

Comment: With The OPs edit, 30 amp circuits are usually 240 volts,  unless you know that the adapter will only use one hot(for 120), then you take a chance of burning up appliance.

Comment: Have you *actually had* nuisance breaker trips so far? Or are you simply preparing for hypothetical future ones?

Comment: No nuisance trips so far.

Comment: @Matthew -- why are you suspecting nuisance trips will be a problem? I suspect either your subs or your ears will blow before the breaker ever trips, there are just too many other limiting factors in that chain of events (only reason amps sometimes trip breakers on inrush is because of toroidal power transformers and the limits of PTC inrush prot)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You got off on the wrong foot to begin with...

because you *started this whole thing* with two serious Code violations.  You thought those things were allowed, *and because of that* you think these other things should be allowed.

So let's reset and correct the mistakes.

First, that "adapter" you've heard about to turn a NEMA 14-50 into four 20A outlets.... one of two things is true.  Either

- it is counterfeit foreign junk that is not legal to sell or use here, (and due to Amazon's cunning lawyers, they're a "Free Trade Zone" and *you're* the importer/smuggler).
- The adapter is UL listed... but you have been incorrect to assume "it's just wires inside".  Not at all: it's an *active PDU*, **effectively a sub-panel potted in plastic**. Internally, each of the receptacles is behind 15A or 20A fuses (and they may be potted and not replaceable, so blowing a fuse "bricks" the adapter. UL is OK with this, in fact it prevents up-fusing).

Second, putting a 20A breaker on a 30A receptacle is a direct and blatant Code violation.  Every breaker must match the receptacles on it, with only two exceptions enumerated in NEC 210.21.

[image]

The two exceptions are for 40A circuits, since NEMA refuses to define a 40A receptacle (they're running out of viable pin configurations).  And for 15A receptacles on 20A circuits **since UL requires 15A receptacles be internally rated 20A**.  This is a "one-off" rule for 15A receptacles *only*.  There is not some principle that makes it scale to other outlet ampacities.

Neither fault should be tolerated. Don't use a NEMA 14-30 and adapter - use dual NEMA 5-20 receptacles wired in MWBC style (feel free to use two *receptacles* of 2 sockets each). Remember neutral must be pigtailed, you cannot use a receptacle as a splice point for neutral.  Leave the breaker 20A.

### Now, with those corrected, your ideas fall apart.

> Code explicitly allows 15A receptacles on 20A circuits for this reason. The question I'm asking is whether there are code compliant approaches with 30A circuits as well.

Nope, that was a "one-off" specifically for 15A receptacles.  That is because UL requires 15A receptacles to be rated for 20A internally.  They make no such requirements of any other size. A 20A receptacle *is not* rated for 30A internally.

> I deliberately oversized it because large amplifiers can have high peak loads. The amplifier uses a NEMA 5-20 plug.

Well, you're allowed to do that all day, all night. *You can **always** use larger wire than is mandated* if you can fit it on the terminals.  However, 20A sockets must have a 20A breaker.

> I want to upsize the breaker from 20A to 30A to prevent nuisance trips for peak loads. But I know that i am not allowed to simply put a 20A NEMA 5-20 receptacle on a 30A breaker.
>
> Hence my question: is there a code compliant receptacle solution that doesn't require an adapter?

Nope.  No way around it, outside of using a sub panel or PDU, which is what you were doing if you used a UL listed adapter.   Any of this defeats your concept, which is to have 30A over-current protection supplying your subwoofers and no 20A protection.

If you really need that, you should talk to your subwoofer supplier about subwoofers that are designed and UL Listed to take a 30A power supply.

Although rather than seeking a wild one-off design like that, for the same wattage, you would be better off seeking European 230V subwoofers designed for their larger 230V/16A circuits.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. To clarify, I installed a 20A breaker, 10awg wiring, and 20A receptacles, all pigtailed. I was wondering if I had a safe opportunity to go to a 30A breaker, which it seems I don't.

Comment: @Matthew -- the "adapters" you see from NEMA 14-30 to 2x NEMA 5-20 are indeed little PDUs (I believe I've seen some with replaceable fuses, though)

Comment: If one wants to be able to use household devices at a location with a 30A receptacle, would there be any code-related problem with replacing the 30A receptacle with a subpanel that's attached to a few 20A receptacles, each on a 20A circuit?

Comment: @supercat as long as the circuit now feeder is 4-wire, should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the device (amplifier, speakers, etc.) is designed for a 20A circuit with a 20A plug, then that is all that should be needed. There are some occasional exceptions, but if any of those applied then they should be documented in the installation instructions. You are already using an MWBC, so you have 2 x 20A already. If you have more than 2 devices that each need most of a 20A circuit, *add another circuit*.

A normal, approved (e.g., UL listed) device for a 20A circuit will:

- Use 16A or less on a continuous basis (e.g., heater)
- Use up to 20A for a short time (e.g., minutes)
- May use more than 20A for a few seconds (e.g., motor startup)

If a device needs more than 16A continuous, more than 20A for normal usage beyond startup, or significantly more than 20A even in startup, then you may need a larger circuit. But you can't do that on your own.

What are the specifications - peak and continuous power (Watts) for each device?

What, if any, recommendations does the manufacture make (in marketing or installation instructions)?

(A separate question is why anyone would actually need speakers that use that much power. But the question is valid because it could be tools or computers or whatever. But remind me to put in earplugs before stopping by your house.)

Comment: Manufacturer recommended a dedicated 20A circuit, which is what I installed. I oversized the wires because it seemed reasonable knowing there would be peak loads. It is not necessary to use a 30A breaker, I was wondering if there were code-compliant no-adapter options

Comment: Have you had any actual "nuisance trips"?

Comment: None. Also it's new.

Comment: This is good info but I'm less concerned about whether a 30A breaker is *required* ( I know it isn't) but interested in whether I have safe and compliant options to use a 30A breaker without adapters at the receptacles.

Comment: AIUI (not being a code expert or an electrician), the *primary* use of a breaker is to protect the wire, and the secondary use is to protect the connected devices. There was a recent question regarding a device (I think it was a welder) which specifically instructed to use a 5-20 receptacle on a 30A circuit, and it was UL-listed. But with such document usage comes the concern of "what else might somebody plug in" and without such documented usage, this device may be unsafe. The classic failure is a short circuit (or close to it), and in such cases a 30A breaker will trip nearly as fast as a

Comment: 20A breaker. The problem is that there *could* be scenarios where a device fails in a manner such that it allows 30A to flow *and some of the components can't handle that and start a fire* where if the device was on a 20A circuit the circuit would trip and prevent a fire.

Answer (score 1):

Regularly encountering tripping a 20A circuit feeding only one device, here are several reactions I have:

1. You're exceeding 5kW just on the subwoofer amps of a residential indoor sound system.  Really?   I just have to ask ... have you designed the system fit for purpose?  Are you using intentionally inefficient amps?  I'm curious what's the requirement driving this scenario.
2. If in fact you are regularly "nuisance tripping" ... nuisance tripping is tripping.  A historically common way of dealing with that is replacing a 10A fuse with a quarter.  It's a bad idea.  By comparison, does it seem unwise to replace a 20A breaker with a 30 just because *one component*, the in-wall wiring, can accommodate it?  Do you know that what you regard as a nuisance is not, in fact, merely *limited* to being a nuisance by virtue of the circuit breaker, without which it would be a "nuisance fire"?
3. I don't think there's a 20A receptacle "designed for 30A passthrough" in the same way as the 15-for-20 ones that are common.  IE, you can't do what you want in the wall.  But maybe you can do it outside the wall.
4. I can't see how "code" or anything other than common sense would stop you from doing this *outside* the wall.  Build a "power bar" with a 30A plug and one 20A socket.  It may be a fire hazard but it's not breaking code, if you just want to focus on that one narrow objective.  But that brings us back to defining "nuisance".

Comment: I'm not encountering any trips, only exploring whether I have a code compliant and safe way to plug devices into a 30A circuit without an adapter. It's sounding more and more like the answer is "no."

Comment: Safe? probably not.  If your amp and its power cord are designed for 20A and specify a 20A breaker, they may not have any additional protection such as an internal fuse.   You're relying on the circuit breaker for all the overcurrent protection.  If you knew there was an internal 20A fuse, it would be a lot safer but then ... the fuse would blow wouldn't it?  Compliant? Gets hazy.   If it's not part of your house and you're not selling it, I'm not sure what regulations govern what kinds of frankenplugs you can use in device cabling.

Comment: @Matthew you say here you're not getting any trips, nuisance or otherwise. Why, then, are you looking at alleviating nuisance trips?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only breaker drawing a heavy load, your concerns are unfounded.

If all the other breakers are being loaded fully, say a panel that controls all the lighting in a commercial building, the NEC would call for an 80% derate for each circuit, which means 20 amp breakers serving 16 amps of lighting.

And perhaps more breakers, a bigger panel, etc.

Breakers generate heat that makes them trip sooner. But it takes a whole panel of warm breakers...

Comment: This is good info but I'm less concerned about whether a 30A breaker is *required* ( I know it isn't) but interested in whether I have safe and compliant options to use a 30A breaker without adapters at the receptacles